# Can you combine CSS variables to include the property and the value?

Tags: css

While I know you can't write variables like

```
root: {
--aic: align-items:center;;
}
```

Is there anyway to get round this, by combining the various parts seperately? The obvious obstical here is the requirement of the colon inside the variable.

i.e.

```
root: {
    --ai: align-items:;
    --center: center;
    --aic:
    var(--ai)
    var(--center);
    }

.myclass {var(--aic);}
```

Comment: No, not possible unfortunately

Comment: I wish it was, I've been down this exact road before trying to create a customisable template/framework

Comment: What about using a stand in text "colon-goes-here" then at rending time using JS to swap out on the fly? Probably performance issues, but just an idea?

Comment: Maybe, the only way I could think to do this would be to use `data-attributes` and then create a `<style>` element with JS -- it's going to get messy though, and there will be performance considerations for sure. Why not just set it up with classes? Like what's the end goal here that you want to have custom properties as declarations?

Comment: I use a lot of shorthand utility class name like jcc aic fxr tac would be handy to be able to just use those as variables inside class names save time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my comment on your question, you can use classes to achieve something similar. But you can't use custom properties as CSS properties, only values -- it's the same as saying for example `margin: margin: var(--customMargin);;`

```css
/* Layout unrelated to answer */
div { border: 1px solid black; color: white }
.varText { background-color: red }
.varPad { background-color: blue }
.varText.varPad { background-color: green }


/* Answer */
:root { --size: 1rem }

.varText { font-size: var(--size) }
.varPad { padding: var(--size) }
```

```html
<div class="varText">
  Size Text only to root variable
</div>
<div class="varText" style="--size: 2rem">
  Size Text only to inline variable
</div>
<div class="varPad">
  Size Padding only to root variable
</div>
<div class="varPad" style="--size: 2rem">
  Size Padding only to inline variable
</div>
<div class="varText varPad">
  Size Text and Padding to root variable
</div>
<div class="varText varPad" style="--size: 2rem">
  Size Text and Padding to inline variable
</div>
```

Comment: The idea was that I could use my shorthand utility class names as variables inside of classes.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to switch to SCSS and use a `@mixin`. Read more about it [here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin).

Here's a [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ev2shx59/4/).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="test">TEST</div>
```

**SCSS:**

```
:root {
    --text_color: red;
    --background_color: gold;
}

@mixin my_mixin {
  color: var(--text_color);
  background-color: var(--background_color);
}

#test {
  @include my_mixin;
}
```